# AJS customize the html to show only certain parts in ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-include

I am able to include a html file into my angular application (ng-include), but i don't want all the content in the html to be shown in my application (it is not an angular application and its conent cant be changed. so ng-show and ng-hide didnt work)

Below is the sample code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
</script>
```

myTable.htm

```
<html>
  <head>this is head</head>
  <body>
<div> test
<h1 id="needToDispalythis">ds,<span>something</span></h1>
</div></body>
</html>
```

here i want only the conent with id **needToDispalythis** needs to be displayed. I tried with directive, but not able to achiheve it. Any help or pointers

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can simply use jQuery to hide the other elements except the element with ID *needToDisplayThis* like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elemToShow = $('#needToDisplayThis');
  $('body').html('<div><h1>'+elemToShow.html()+'</h1></div>');
});
```

---

Firstly, your *ng-include* **myTable.html** should not contain the `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` tags. Use only the markup that you want to render, ie: `<div> test<h1 id="needToDispalythis">ds,<span>something</span></h1></div>`.

So your main html should look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>this is head</head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
      <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And your included html should look like this:

```
<div> 
  <span>test</span>
  <h1 id="needToDispalythis">ds,<span>something</span></h1>
</div>
```

Now to only show the `<h1>` element you need to hide the `<span>` element, so add an `ng-hide` attribute to that:

```
<span ng-hide="hideThis">test<span/>
```

Now simply set the hideThis variable on the `$scope` to true:

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.hideThis = true;
   });
</script>
```

---

So finally, your main html looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>this is head</head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
      <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.hideThis = true;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and your myTable.html looks like this:

```
<div> 
  <span ng-hide="hideThis">test<span/>
  <h1>ds,<span>something</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding "your ng-include myTable.html should not contain the <html><head></head><body></body></html>" this html is external and will  be got dynamically, so i cant directly editt the html. I want it to be edited through js

Comment: @Cedric, are you able to use jQuery, then please look at the update.